# Iquery linq expression powering autocomplete breaks after 8 years - sql function evaluation requires all threads to run

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-6

I have been using the following linq expression for many years to power an autocomplete dropdown list of client names.

```
        {
            try
            {
                var users = _context.UserProfiles.Select(up => new UserDropDownViewModel()
                {
                    LastName = up.LastName,
                    UserName = up.UserName,
                    UserId = up.UserId,
                    LfName = up.LastName + ", " + up.FirstName

                });

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                {
                    users = users.Where(p => p.LfName.StartsWith(text));
                }

                var ret = Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                return ret;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)   
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
            }

            return null;
            
        }
```

The procedure does not generate an exception, but when I hover over the ret, I see a red sql and "The function evaluation requires all threads to run"   Any suggestions on how I might fix this greatly appreciated.  I'm running in a .Net Framework 4.6.1 environment.

Comment: That's a debugger message that has nothing do to with any problems. An `IQueryable` is a *query*, not data so the debugger can't display anything without first running the query. In the code you posted `users` is still a query until `Json(users,`. If you want to inspect the data execute the query with eg `var userResults=users.ToList()` or `var userResults= await users.ToListAsync();`

Comment: Is there an *actual* problem? Except the delays caused by the inefficient filtering? ` p.LfName.StartsWith(text)` works on a function result which means it can't take advantage of any indexes covering `LastName` or `FirstName`. The database will have to scan the entire table to find matches. If `text` contains no commas you can use `.UserProfiles.Where(up=>up.LastName.StartsWith(text))` to speed up the search

Comment: You must be getting an exception for return to be null.  What does the exception say?  the exception should be Console.Write(ex.Message); or Console.Write(ex.TraceStack);